# Asymptotic of an integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, asymptotics, hamiltonian-mechanics

Let 
\begin{equation*}
    V(x) = -\big(2-\sin(2\pi x) - \sin(2\pi \sqrt{2}x)\big)^\gamma
\end{equation*}
for some $\gamma \in (0,1]$. Define for each $r<0$ the number
$$a_r = \min\{a>0: V(a) = r\}$$
I want to find the asymptotic behavior of the following integral
$$ s_r = \int_0^{a_r}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2(r-V(x))}}$$
as $r\rightarrow 0^-$. One thing I have in mind is, we can show that 
$$ \frac{C_1}{t^{2\gamma}} \leq \min_{[0,t]}|V(x)| \leq \frac{C_2}{t^{2\gamma}}$$, therefore as $|r| = \min_{[0,a_r]} |V(x)|$ one can deduce
$$ C_1^{\frac{1}{2\gamma}}|r|^{-\frac{1}{2\gamma}} \leq |a_r|\leq C_2^\frac{1}{2\gamma} r^{-\frac{1}{2\gamma}}$$
but I failed to proceed further for $s_r$.

---

This question arises from my attempt to understand the following Hamiltonian 
$$H(x,p) = \frac{|p|^2}{2} +V(x)$$
Fixing a parameter $\varepsilon$, I am interested in the behavior of 
$$ \varepsilon \eta(\varepsilon^{-1})$$
as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+$ where $\eta$ solves the Euler-Lagrange equation 
$$ \ddot{\eta}(s) = -V'(\eta(s)), \qquad \text{on}\; (0,\varepsilon^{-1})$$
and $\eta(0) = 0$. Using the conservation of energy
$$ \frac{|\dot{\eta}(s)|^2}{2} + V(\eta(s)) = r$$
we can deduce the ODE
$$ |\dot{\eta}(s)| = \sqrt{2(r-V(\eta(s)))}, \qquad{on}\;(0,\varepsilon^{-1})$$
The value $s_r$ above is the time it takes for $\eta_r$ to reach to $a_r$, when $r<0$. It is easy to see that, for a fixed $r>0$ we have
$$ \varepsilon \eta_r(\varepsilon^{-1}) \leq \varepsilon a_r \rightarrow 0$$
as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$. The question is, can I do that uniformly, in the sense that either 
$$ |\varepsilon \eta_r(\varepsilon^{-1})| \leq C \varepsilon ^\alpha $$
or 
$$ |\varepsilon \eta_r(\varepsilon^{-1}) - M(r,\varepsilon)| \leq C \varepsilon ^\alpha $$
for some $M_r \rightarrow 0$ as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: (i) Where does this problem arise? (ii) Did you use the continued fraction for $\sqrt2$ to get $ \frac{C_1}{t^{2\gamma}} \leq \min_{[0,t]}|V(x)| \leq \frac{C_2}{t^{2\gamma}}$? (iii) I think there are typos in your bounds on $a_r$ (which is a generalized inverse of $V(a)$).

Comment: (i) This arises from an attempt to quantify the long time average of the solution to the ODE
$$ \begin{cases}
|\dot{\eta}(s)| &= \sqrt{2(r-V(\eta(s)))}, s>0\\
\eta(0) &= 0.
\end{cases}$$ 

(ii) I used Diophantine Approximation of $\sqrt{2}$ to show that inequality (I think it relates to the continued fraction for $\sqrt{2}$ as you said)

(iii) Thanks for that, I did have a typo.

Comment: We can see that (numerically or analytically), for a.e. $r<0$ the solution above $\eta(s)$ is periodic, the point here is I am trying to quantify how large is the size of the orbit changes in terms of the time $\eta(s)$ needs to reach to these maximum points.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It is still unclear to me where your ODE arises.

Comment: It arises from the conservation of energy $\frac{|\dot{\eta}|^2}{2} + V(\eta) = r$, where $\eta$ solves the Euler-Lagrange equation $\ddot{\eta} = -V'(\eta)$. I am looking at the the minimizer with negative energy.

Comment: I guess my questions really were about the function $V$: where does it arise?

Comment: So classical mechanic Hamiltonians are well studied for mostly periodic potential, I am considering quasi-periodic potential, and this is the simplest one. The power $\gamma$ is just for technicality.